# Remove all selected elements from JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to remove the selected elements from a JList. I know how to remove one which is

```
((DefaultListModel) jList.getModel()).remove(index);
```

However; is there a way to remove my selected indices? I know of the function

```
list.getSelectedIndices();
```

Which returns an Int Array. I figured if I iterate through that to remove the indices it should work however I'm getting errors from that (Assuming because the indice # is going down.

Comment: try iterating in reverse order

Comment: Remove the largest indices first. Or get the selected **values** (not indices), and call https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeElement-java.lang.Object-.

Comment: If you want to remove items from a list you are iterating you can use an iterator

Comment: You can't iterate through a list and remove its items while iterating it, that will most likely give you a concurrent modication exception, use iterator

Answer (score 2):

Removing an element will "shift" all the elements that come after it, which is probably the cause of the errors you've been seeing. One way around this is to iterate over those indexes **backwards**, so you never handle the shifted part of the list:

```
DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) jList.getModel();
int[] indexes = jList.getSelectedIndexes();
for (int i = indexes.length; i >= 0; --i) {
    model.remove(indexes[i]);
}
```

Comment: For some reason that's removing more than 1 element at a time.

Comment: @DotSlashShell There was a bug in there; I fixed it; try again.